# Javascript, how to receive data from json array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object and I want to loop through the items in the object and display their data. when I do a console log of the json object I get the following in the console:

[image: json object]

My question is, how do I loop through this data and expose the 'name' 'songId' and 'upvote'?

I've tried the following

```
var json = JSON.parse(jsonObject);
console.log(json);
$.each(json, function (key, value) {
    console.log(value);

    //   console.log(value.name[key]);
});
```

Any help or suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot it looks like what you want to iterate is `json.playlists` not `json`

```
var json = JSON.parse(jsonObject);
    console.log(json.playlists);
    $.each(json.playlists, function (key, value) {
        console.log(value.songID);
        console.log(value.name);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an object containing an array of objects, so to loop through it you need something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.playlists.length; i++) {
    console.log(json.playlists[i].name);
    console.log(json.playlists[i].songID);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your json is an `object` having a key named `playlists` as array.

Something like bellow

```
json = {playlists:[{name:"song1",songID:"1"},....]}
```

You have to iterate on this array.

This should work for you.

```
json.playlists.forEach(function (playlist) {
   console.log(playlist.name);
   console.log(playlist.songID);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate from `json.playlists`, since the structure is:

```
Object{
  playlists: [
    {},
  ]
}


$.each(json.playlists, function (key, value) {
  // stuffs to do here
});
```